# I can't see the values of a variable written in a function, in another function

Tags: powershell

Here is my code. My main problem is that I ask for a variable in the function `location`, but when I try to write it in the function `Show-Menu` it apparently is empty.

I made a search around and I found that should be with the global before the variable. Like this:

```
function Show-Menu {
    Param(
        [string]$Title = 'Menu'
    )
    cls
    Write-Host "================ $Title ================"
    Write-Host "                                        "
    Write-Host "The path is $global:path"
    Write-Host "1: Press '1' for IDF config."
    Write-Host "2: Press '2' for MDF config."
    Write-Host "Q: Press 'Q' to quit."
}

function location {
    cls
    $global:path = Read-Host -Prompt "Set path to save your configurations (default C:\Network_configs)"
    #Acuerdate que no funciona bien, por el hecho de tener variables en diferentes funciones. 
    if ([lenght]$global:path -le 1) {
        $global:path = C:\Network_configs
    }
}
```

I expect the output with a path C:\Network_configs in case there is no keyboard entrance, but I have this output:

```
================ Menu ================

The path is 
1: Press '1' for IDF config.
2: Press '2' for MDF config.
Q: Press 'Q' to quit.
Please make a selection:
```

Comment: Where does type `[lenght]` defined?

Comment: To be very honest, i thought count the lenght of the characters. But it doesn´t?

Comment: Besides the word being misspelled you are also trying to use "lenght" as a (non existing) datatype. If you want to get the character count on a string I would suggest reading the basic documentation of Powershell instead of "just trying something" (getting the count of something in Powershell is one of the very first you'll learn doing when learning Powershell)

Comment: Aside from what already has been said there are other issues with your code as well. `$global:path = C:\Network_configs` will throw an error, b/c the statement would try to execute a program/script `C:\Network_configs`. To assign a path string to a variable put the value in quotes (`$global:path = 'C:\Network_configs'`). Also, it's bad practice to modify global variables in functions. Use parameters and return values for the data flow in your scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using global variables is not recommended check out [variable scoping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-6).

However you're very close, try checking for user input, if it is null use the default value.

```
function Show-Menu
{
    Param(
        [string]$Title = 'Menu'
    )
    cls
    Write-Host "================ $Title ================"
    Write-Host "                                        "
    Write-Host "The path is $global:path"
    Write-Host "1: Press '1' for IDF config."
    Write-Host "2: Press '2' for MDF config."
    Write-Host "Q: Press 'Q' to quit."
}
function location
{
    cls
    $userInput = Read-Host -Prompt "Set path to save your configurations (default C:\Network_configs)"
    if ($null -eq $userInput)
    {
        $global:path = 'C:\Network_configs'
    }
    else
    {
        $global:path = $userInput
    }
}
```

Comment: Please avoid formatting code as a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) unless the snippet is actually runnable. Proper code formatting is done with the `{}` button.

Comment: Got it. you are absolutely right. I will keep working to avoid the global variables

Comment: Thanks @AlvaroSenosiainAzpilicueta Please up-vote the answer if it resolved your question.